# Angular router: should a Bootstrap modal be reflected in the route url?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-ui-router

This question is about best practices, regarding whether to render a modal visible using the JS modal() function or to use an Angular router-outlet to display the modal?  Or, whether a modal is even appropriate in Angular.

I just started to read the book "Angular Router" by Victor Savkin (the primary creator of the Angular router), and found this quote near the beginning:

> "In a well-behaved web application, any application state transition results in a URL change, and any URL change results in a state transition."

This would suggest to use routing to display even something like a modal.  Yet doing such seems excessively complex in comparison with just using regular JS to show the modal.

Is a modal an improper construct to be used as such, or is there something similar that should be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I continued reading the book, and have concluded that if someone wants to make use of the routing url state management offered by Angular, then it is best to use a router outlet but not a modal.  Modals "can" be used in such cases, but are absolutely unnecessary since the router and possibly the Animations library will handle the transition to/from the display.  If an application architect, for whatever reason (be it code simplicity or else) doesn't want to register this modal state in the router url, then a modal with standard invokation will suffice.

Refer to the sample application referred to in the textbook to study this usage of a popup without a modal construct. 
 https://github.com/vsavkin/router_mailapp/blob/master/src/app/mail.html.